# How to create Python Matplotlib.pyplot Boxplot with slightly offset entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to create a "boxplot" using the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

fig1, ax1 = pl.subplots()

bp1 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[0::3], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)
bp2 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[1::3], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)
bp3 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[2::3], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)

for box in bp1['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='red', linewidth=2)
for box in bp2['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='green', linewidth=2)
for box in bp2['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='blue', linewidth=2)
```

the code produces 3 different boxplots overlapping each other. I would like to add an offset to "bp2" and "bp3" so that in the end all 3 boxplots are slightly offset to each other for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `positions` argument to `boxplot` to set the horizontal position of the boxes. From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html):

> `positions` array-like, optional
>
> Sets the positions of the boxes. The ticks and limits are automatically set to match the positions. Defaults to `range(1, N+1)` where `N` is the number of boxes to be drawn.

For example, here I set them to 1, 2 and 3:

```
bp1 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[0::3], positions=[1], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)
bp2 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[1::3], positions=[2], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)
bp3 = ax1.boxplot(ampl_times_fbc[2::3], positions=[3], showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Would it also be possible to put all 3 on x=1 while they overlap but slightly offset to the right?

Comment: I guess you can try [1], [1.1], [1.2] and adjust to suit your needs

Comment: And can I somehow hide all positions on the plot except for the first (the 1, 2, 3 shown but 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2 hidden)?